# Illegal character in string(â€‹)

Tags: java

Illegal character in string(â€‹)

**I really don't understand what the problem is.**
text: The score category were provide by the client.​
I am experiencing illegal character problem while handling with the above string.
I've found out some strange character appears at the en the of line when I've put the above text in following url..
url: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

How to resolve this encoding error via coding while doing string operations.

Comment: So, the client provided corrupt/broken data? This is not unheard of. Either clean the data yourself, or ask the client to send you clean data.

Comment: Could you provide an actual code sample? And provide additional logging for the error you're receiving?

Comment: Try reading the original data with encoding UTF-8. If that does not work out, there probably are more than one encoding charset conversions that messed the text up. Or Windows-1252, as that looks like a quoted Euro too, and comma like quotes are missing in ISO-8859-1, Latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

That illegal character(â€‹), I have mentioned is **ZERO WIDTH SPACE** One can replace the character with an empty string using *[\u200B]* regex form.